# Jquery-UI-Map attaching event to info window close?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, maps

I'm having trouble coming figuring out how to attach a info window close event to an info window with the Jquery-UI-Map api (http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/). I'd like to attach a close event within the creation of the info window, or by chaining to the creation of it. Whatever takes the least code and conforms with how the rest of the api is structured.

My current solution is using the google maps api event listeners, it works but I don't like it. I'd prefer a jquery method.

I currently have..

```
self.snMapElement.gmap('openInfoWindow', {'content': infoWindowMarkup}, self.selectedStreetMarker);

                // Setup close event
                google.maps.event.addListener(self.snMapElement.gmap('get', 'iw'), 'closeclick', function(){
                    self.removeSelectedStreetMarker();
                });
```

I would like to use some method, if possible as:

```
self.snMapElement.gmap('openInfoWindow', {'content': infoWindowMarkup}, self.selectedStreetMarker).bind('closeclick', function(){self.removeSelectedStreetMarker()});
```